# RMSE and MAE of predicted values is better than benchmark, but predicted values are only closer to actual values half the time

Tags: r, machine-learning

I'm trying to learn some machine learning basics to predict football players' fantasy football points.

I've built a dataset and done some modelling. My plan was to compare my predictions to projections made by fantasy football experts.

For my test data, the mean absolute error of my predictions = 66.2, while the mean absolute error of the experts' projections = 109.3. The RMSE of my predictions on the test set = 90.2, while the experts' projections have an RMSE of 150.1.

I thought this would mean that my model's projections would beat the expert projections consistently. However, this was not the case. When I look at the specific individuals in my test set, my model's predictions only beat the experts' predictions 56% of the time.

Does anyone have any ideas for why this might be? If so, what could I do to try to address the issue?

(One thing I noticed is that my model doesn't do well at projecting the highest scoring players. It was worse than the experts' on all of the top 5, though it did great in the middle tiers.)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your model is overfitting on the data.  That will make it look like your model is great during testing, but it won't be accurate to new data in real life.

Comment: I was modelling using k-fold cross-validation, though. (The 66.2 MAE is from the cross-validated model.) I was hoping that would deal with the overfitting concern. Would it?

Answer (score 0):

The MAE and RMSE metrics tell you that your model has, on average, lower error than the experts' model. This does not necessarily mean your model will have a lower error for all individual observations, consider this example:
There are three data points, the expert model has errors 5, 5, and 20 -- this gives as Mean Absolute Error 30.

Your model improves on that last error significantly and achieves errors 6, 5, 14 and total MAE 25.

Your MAE is lower than the expert MAE (holds true for RMSE), but your model achieves a lower error only in a single instance (1/3 of the time). You could construct even an example where your MAE is lower than the expert model, but most of the time, your residuals are actually higher.

> it did great in the middle tears

My guess is this is where you achieved the better results, but perhaps your model is consistently worse for the higher and lower tiers.

Let me know if this helps!